# Keyboard doesn't show on focus in alert dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, focus, alert

I have a dialog which I extend from custom PopupDialog.

The problem is that the keyboard won't appear on focus EditText field . I've tried with clearFlags and other things, but the problem is still there.

```
public class PopupDialog<RESULT> extends AlertDialog {
private final View mContentView;
private final AppActivity mActivity;

/**
 * Sets the activity and Content View.
 *
 * @param activity
 *            The activity which is used.
 * @param content
 *            The main content of dialog window.
 */
public PopupDialog(final AppActivity activity, final int content) {
    super(activity);
    mActivity = activity;

    // Set the content
    mContentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.z__dialog, null, false);
    setView(mContentView);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

    setView(mContentView, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Set the background to white
    setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);
    show();

    // Inflate the content
    View.inflate(activity, content, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.dialog_content)).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(700, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added one EditText in xml, and disable focus in code `this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

and it's working now. not clean, but it's working.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialog_frame"
    style="@style/vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <requestFocus />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_content"
        style="@style/block" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editext"
        style="@style/block"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_buttons"
        style="@style/horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_middle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your EditText is not focusable or is not focusable in Touch Mode, but can't know for sure without seeing the xml for that view. Can you post it please?

Comment: Check the sections in here under Focus Handling and Touch Mode: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html You need to add android:focusableInTouchMode(true); to the views you want to request focus.

Comment: Still nothing. Also I've checked if every view isFocusableInTouchMode() and it is, but keyboard doesn't appear.